# Why cant I inline call to res.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I have and expressjs application and on a specific route I call a function that responds with a user from the database by calling `res.json` with the database document as parameter. I use promise based libraries and I wanted to inline the callback where I am putting the database document in the response. But the program fails when I do so. Can somebody explain why? I also wonder why inlined calls to `console.log` actually do work. Is there some fundamental difference between the two methods `res.json` and `console.log`?

Here is an example of what works and what does not work. Assume `getUserFromDatabase()` returns a promise of a user document.

```
//This works
var getUser = function(req, res) {
    getUserFromDatabase().then(function(doc) {
        res.json(doc);
    });    
} 

//This does not work (the server never responds to the request)
var getUserInline = function(req, res) {
    getUserFromDatabase().then(res.json);    
} 

//This works (the object is printed to the console)
var printUser = function(req, res) {
    getUserFromDatabase().then(console.log);    
}
```

Comment: It looks like a binding problem. http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `json` function loses its correct `this` binding when used like that since `.then` is going to invoke it directly without reference to the `res` parent object, so bind it:

```
var getUserInline = function(req, res) {
    getUserFromDatabase().then(res.json.bind(res));    
}
```

Comment: Could this be considered a flaw in the library or is there no way around it when designing the res object?

Comment: This is just how JavaScript works. The `res.json` function could be pre-bound by the library for you but that would be very unconventional in javascript. CoffeeScript allows pre-binding object oriented methods with the fat arrow ("=>") operator, FYI.

Comment: @LudwigMagnusson `res.json` is not a function but a method - that means it is dependent on `this`. While it may be annoying in this situation, it performs much better than functions that need to carry their context with them because it can be statically allocated. `Response` class could automatically bind its methods but that is a huge performance loss when `res.json` can be called normally as a method (most often it can).