# Why can't I pass Node request methods directly to Bluebird promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

It should be entirely possible to run something like the following:

```
function someMiddleware (req, res, next) {        
    someAsyncBluebirdOperation().then(res.json);
}
```

But if you pass any methods of a `res` objects directly as a reference in a resolve handler, you will get the following, unhelpful error:

```
[TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined] __stackCleaned__: true
```

If you wrap the call to `res.json` in another function, everything seems fine:

```
function someMiddleware (req, res, next) {        

    function wrapper(result) {
        res.json(result);
    }

    someAsyncBluebirdOperation().then(wrapper);
}
```

I can only assume there is some issue with binding/scope happening, but having to wrap the call in another function feels completely unnecessary.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue. The `.then` method simply takes a function to call. `res.json` is a function. It should accept it.

Comment: read that http://stackoverflow.com/a/18019561/4478897

Comment: `res.json` is not a function but a method - that means it is dependent on `this`. While it may be annoying in this situation, it performs much better than functions that need to carry their context with them because it can be statically allocated. `Response` class could automatically bind its methods but that is a huge performance loss when `res.json` can be called normally as a method (most often it can).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it requires to be called as a method, which `.then` does not do. Try to use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
function someMiddleware (req, res, next) {        
    someAsyncBluebirdOperation().then(res.json.bind(res));
}
```